# Custom dimension tracking for EACH transactionProduct with Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Is there a way to track custom dimensions using Google Tag Manager for each product in transactionProducts?

For example I'm using the dataLayer as outlined here:

https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107169?hl=en

As an example What I'm currently passing to the dataLayer is

```
'transactionProducts': [{
   'sku': 'DD44',
   'name': 'IPhone 7',
   'category': 'Phones',
   'price': 11.99,
   'quantity': 1,
   'network': 'EE',
   'term': 12
 },{
   'sku': 'DD44',
   'name': 'IPhone 7',
   'category': 'Phones',
   'price': 11.99,
   'quantity': 1,
   'network': 'O2',
   'term': 24
```

}]

The 'network' and 'term' are not the standard part of GA tracking. I've set these up as custom dimensions with the scope set to 'product'.

If I navigate to Google Analytics -> E-Commerce -> Product Performance, I can see the newly set up custom dimensions in the 'secondary dimension' dropdown however no data ever gets pulled through. If i set a custom dimension in the root array (so not linked to a product) this pulls in fine.

Is this the limitation or can I have custom dimensions for each product and am doing it wrong?

Comment: You can have product scoped dimensions. How does your setup for the custom dimensions look like (I'm not sure if you are aware that you cannot use the names, but have to use the keyword "dimension" plus the numeric index) ?

Comment: Followed the instructions to create the dimensions from https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6164990?hl=en&ref_topic=6333310 - the 'Set custom dimension values from the data layer' section.

Also updated the above transactionProducts array to use dimension1, dimension2 etc, placed a test order and still nothing.

Comment: works fine in my tests with product scoped custom dimension #1
dataLayer.push({
  "event": "productClick",
  "ecommerce": {
    "click": {
      "actionField": {
        "list": "homepage"
      },
      "products": [{
        "id": "f6be8",
        "name": "Comverges T-Shirt",
        "price": "33.00",
        "brand": "Comverges",
        "category": "T-Shirts",
        "position": "2",
  "dimension1": "EE"
      }]
    }
  }
});